# Hosting iOS back-end app logic on google cloud

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I have an iOS app with its backend logic written in `PHP` and using `MySQL` on `Cloud SQL`. I'm trying to figure out how to connect the iOS app to the `PHP` files through `Google App Engine`. I'm using `Standard environment`.

I was looking into `Google Cloud Endpoints` but they only seem to work for `Java` and `Python` files. Have I misunderstood this?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers :)

Comment: Google Cloud Endpoints works for any language, if used in App Engine Flexible environment, GCE, GKE, or other computing environments. Only the App Engine Standard environment version is limited by language.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using GAE Standard, you would be using [Cloud Endpoints Framework](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks), which does not support PHP.

Your options are:

1. Use GAE Flexible and Cloud Endpoints OpenAPI, which does support PHP.
2. Don't use Cloud Endpoints, instead use [Apigee](https://cloud.google.com/apigee-api-management/).
3. Don't use Cloud Endpoints, instead use a 3rd party API framework such as [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/)